# System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, dapper

1. I would have expected the queryOutput to be materialized?
2. Why
   is there the invalid attempt to call fieldcount when it alreadyhas the IEnumerable?

---

```
/// <summary>
   /// Get all columns for a certain table
   /// </summary>
   public async Task<List<Tuple<string, string, int?>>> GetAllColumnsFromTableAsync(string tableName)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string, int?>> result;
    string query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= @tableName";
    using (IDbConnection db = DbConnection) 
    { 
        IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, int?>> queryOutput = await db.QueryAsync<string, string, int?, Tuple<string, string, int?>>
            (query, Tuple.Create, new { tableName = tableName }, null, false, splitOn: "*");
        result = queryOutput.ToList(); // System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.
    }

    if (result is not null && result.Count > 0)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

---

- making this a non async method works. so it MUST be "tuple"+"dapper"+"async"

ref: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/745

**update:**

1. when replacing the tuple with named tuples the query in itself
   works.

   ```
   public async Task<List<(string COLUMN_NAME, string DATA_TYPE, int? CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)>> GetAllColumnsFromTableAsync2(string tableName)
   {
       const string query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= @tableName";
       using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring);
       var output = await connection.QueryAsync<(string COLUMN_NAME, string DATA_TYPE, int? CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)>
               (query, new { tableName = tableName });
       return output.ToList();
   }
   ```

I have a further problem but that is another question.

Comment: The Dapper doc states that query results are List instances, hence I usually do the following:
`return connection.Query<`MyDto>(sql) as IList<MyDto>;`

Comment: You need to await the results before you exit the using block.

Comment: @john-wu as far as i know i am awaiting the results with  "await" ? (and placing {} around the using  i added just to see if this would be of influence since they are not needed

Comment: @RoarS. as far as i know i do 'tolist' ?

Comment: My guess is that the `DbConnection` is closed too early. I can't see from your code where it is created though. That can be verified/falsified If you give it a try to replace that part of your code with the same code from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper's supposed to make your life easier, and that code looks complicated.

If you use a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names) with named fields, you can just use Dapper's auto mapping to materialize.  EG:

```
static class DbExtensions
{
    public static async Task<List<(string COLUMN_NAME, string DATA_TYPE, int? CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)>> GetAllColumnsFromTableAsync(this IDbConnection db, string tableName, string schema = "dbo")
    {
        string query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= @tableName and TABLE_SCHEMA=@schema";
        var queryOutput = await db.QueryAsync<(string COLUMN_NAME, string DATA_TYPE, int? CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)>(query, new { tableName = tableName, schema = schema });
        return queryOutput.ToList();
    }
}
```

Also note there's a bug in your query if you have multiple tables with the same name, so you should specify the schema.

Comment: Neat trick, always using .item. Will refactor this backwards in codebase. this works but... i need to use the  "await" before using from Roar S. his answer also otherwise my other parallel healthchecks show intermittent sql errors.

Comment: What does "use the "await" before using" mean?

Comment: The answer of Roar S. shows this he uses " await using var connection" so the word "await" in that line.

Comment: It doesn't _do_ anything to `await` a constructor.  They are always syncronous.

Comment: I will check further on why the using DOES actually solve the problem although it does not do anything. It does something since there are no intermittent errors but probably as not the main reason but a side effect.